# Add custom font

Tags: objective-c, ios, fonts, interface-builder

Is it possible to apply custom (added to the app) font to UILabel text via UIBuilder or it can be done only programmatically ?

I have already added

```
Fonts provided by application
```

key in application plist

Comment: I am also using custom fonts, but I have found that the only way to utilize them is programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can only be done programmaticaly, but it is simple: crate a subclass of UILabel and then overwrite the awakeFromNib method:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
   [super awakeFromNib];
   self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFancyFont" size:self.font.pointSize];
}
```

(with this method you keep the font size you set in IB.)

In the Identity Inspector in IB you have to set the label to the class you created, in "Custom Class" (where it says "UILabel" now).